# How to do memcmp() in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert some of my code from Objective-C to Swift.  One method that I'm having trouble with does a comparison of a `CBUUID` with an `UInt16`. This was fairly straight-forward in Objective-C, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a good way to do this in Swift.

Here's the Objective-C version:

```
/*
 *  @method compareCBUUIDToInt
 *
 *  @param UUID1 UUID 1 to compare
 *  @param UUID2 UInt16 UUID 2 to compare
 *
 *  @returns 1 (equal) 0 (not equal)
 *
 *  @discussion compareCBUUIDToInt compares a CBUUID to a UInt16 representation of a UUID and returns 1
 *  if they are equal and 0 if they are not
 *
 */
-(int) compareCBUUIDToInt:(CBUUID *)UUID1 UUID2:(UInt16)UUID2 {
    char b1[16];
    [UUID1.data getBytes:b1];
    UInt16 b2 = [self swap:UUID2];
    if (memcmp(b1, (char *)&b2, 2) == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

My (untested) version of this method in Swift got much more complicated and I'm hoping that I'm just missing some better ways to use the language:

```
func compareCBUUID(CBUUID1: CBUUID, toInt CBUUID2: UInt16) -> Int {
    let uuid1data = CBUUID1.data
    let uuid1count = uuid1data.length / sizeof(UInt8)
    var uuid1array = [UInt8](count: uuid1count, repeatedValue: 0)
    uuid1data.getBytes(&uuid1array, length: uuid1count * sizeof(UInt8))

    // @todo there's gotta be a better way to do this
    let b2: UInt16 = self.swap(CBUUID2)
    var b2Array = [b2 & 0xff, (b2 >> 8) & 0xff]
    if memcmp(&uuid1array, &b2Array, 2) == 0 {
        return 1
    }
    return 0
}
```

There are two things that seem to complicate things.  First, it isn't possible to declare a fixed sized buffer in Swift, so the `char b1[16]` in ObjC becomes 3 lines in Swift.  Second, I don't know of a way to do a `memcmp()` in Swift with a UInt16.  The compiler complains that:

```
'UInt16' is not convertible to '@value inout $T5'
```

So that's where the clunky step comes in where I separate out the UInt16 into a byte array by hand.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corresponding Swift code for `char b1[16]` would be

```
var b1 = [UInt8](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
```

and for the byte swapping you can use the "built-in" method `byteSwapped`
or `bigEndian`.
Casting the pointer for `memcpy()` is a bit tricky.

The direct translation of your Objective-C code to Swift would be (untested!):

```
var b1 = [UInt8](count: 16, repeatedValue: 0)
CBUUID1.data.getBytes(&b1, length: sizeofValue(b1))
var b2: UInt16 = CBUUID2.byteSwapped
// Perhaps better:
// var b2: UInt16 = CBUUID2.bigEndian
if memcmp(UnsafePointer(b1), UnsafePointer([b2]), 2) == 0 {
    // ...
}
```

However, if you define `b1` as an `UInt16` array then you don't need
`memcmp()` at all:

```
var b1 = [UInt16](count: 8, repeatedValue: 0)
CBUUID1.data.getBytes(&b1, length: sizeofValue(b1))
var b2: UInt16 = CBUUID2.bigEndian
if b1[0] == b2 {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I dig it!  I didn't know about the `byteSwapped` thing, pretty slick!